# Custom enum implementation Java

Tags: java, enums, stack-overflow

I am trying to implement some kind of custom enum - a class which would act like enum and would implement its methods. I need to pass a set of values make them final and do operations like ordinal, valueOf, values. 
Here is my implementation:

```
public class CustomEnum {
    private static final Map<String,CustomEnum> valuesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static final List<CustomEnum> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public CustomEnum(String...data) {
        for(String s : data){
            final CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(s);
            valuesMap.put(s, customEnum);
            valuesList.add(customEnum);
        }
    }

    public CustomEnum valueOf(final String data){
        if (data == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        final CustomEnum customEnum = valuesMap.get(data);
        if(customEnum == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return customEnum;
    }

    public CustomEnum[] values(){
        return valuesList.toArray(new CustomEnum[valuesList.size()]);
    }

    public int ordinal(){
        return valuesList.indexOf(this);
    }

}
```

And when I create an instance of a class I get StackOverflow error:

```
 CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum("white");
```

I understand why this error is happening, but I do not know how elese I can implement such class. The question is how I can change my implementation but still keep all the methods and data structures (arraylists, map) working?
I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to reinvent the wheel here?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to construct a new `CustomEnum` inside your constructor?

Comment: @JoeC  Because I have such a task

Comment: Why are you creating a `class`, but not `enum` ?

Comment: @shmosel well, I can pass it as this to map but it's still doesn't change the question

Comment: @RafaelOsipov according to the task I need to implement it with a class, not enum

Comment: But of course it does. Why do you think you're getting a stack overflow?

Comment: @shmosel obviously, because I create an instance of the same class in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that the constructor as written is actually a factory. Move that functionality out of the constructor and you're good.

```
public static class CustomEnum {
    private static final Map<String,CustomEnum> valuesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static final List<CustomEnum> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String data;

    public CustomEnum(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public CustomEnum valueOf(final String data){
        if (data == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        final CustomEnum customEnum = valuesMap.get(data);
        if(customEnum == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return customEnum;
    }

    public CustomEnum[] values(){
        return valuesList.toArray(new CustomEnum[valuesList.size()]);
    }

    public int ordinal(){
        return valuesList.indexOf(this);
    }

    public static void create(String...data) {
        for(String s : data){
            final CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(s);
            valuesMap.put(s, customEnum);
            valuesList.add(customEnum);
        }
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    CustomEnum.create("white");
}
```

Comment: how can I call all my methods now from the created instance? Should I make them static or return CustomEnum from create method, for example?

Comment: You need more clarity on what you want. Using static fields means that all created `CustomEnum`s will be recorded in your collections so you can make `values` `static` if you like but you need to decide what you are looking for in terms of functionality.

Comment: In terms of functionality, I want to create my CustomEnum instance with multiple arguments and call methods  - values, valueOf and ordinal.

Comment: @Cassie - Consider carefully the effect of using `static` collections. This means that there will only ever be one set of enums which can be accessed via `values()`. If that is not what you want then you need to redesign. Perhaps use inner classes for the enum instances.

Comment: inner class is a good idea. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: do you think this inner class should be static or not?

Comment: @Cassie - No. You will be making the collections non-static and the inner class needs access to them.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be a second constructor:

```
public CustomEnum(String s) {
    valuesMap.put(s, this);
    valuesList.add(this);
}
```

The one constructor you have is calling itself endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a design problem.
The public constructor values `static` fields.
So at each time a `CustomEnum` created, their content is overwritten.

So these collections don't have invariant elements :

```
private static final Map<String,CustomEnum> valuesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
private static final List<CustomEnum> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

To solve your problem, you have two ways.
And in any cases, you have to make the constructor `private` to allow invariant and decouple the global construction that creates all `CustomEnum` instances from the creation of each one of them :

```
private CustomEnum(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

First way : Provide the constant values directly in the class (as enum does).

```
static{
    String[] data = {....}; // constant values
    for(String s : data){
        final CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(s);
        valuesMap.put(s, customEnum);
        valuesList.add(customEnum);
    }
}
```

Second way : make  fields and methods not `static` and allows to create more than one `CustomEnum` with different values.

```
private final Map<String,CustomEnum> valuesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
private final List<CustomEnum> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(); 

public static void of(String... data) {
    for(String d : data){
        final CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(d);
        valuesMap.put(d, customEnum);
        valuesList.add(customEnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: according to the second way I wouldn't be able to use valuesMap and valuesList in my create method for building an instance of the class, as this method is static.

Comment: The second way supposes that you remove all these `static` modifier as I started to do for the fields.

Comment: But how would I instantiate a class if create method is not static and constructor is private?

Comment: with the `of()` method that is a factory method.